# Image loading inconsistent with Jekyll + GitHub Pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I've recently created a Jekyll/Github pages site in the hopes of starting a small blog to share thoughts and side projects. After writing my first post, I've realized that some but not all of my images within the post are not working. I have been trying for hours to figure out why in vain. Below is my assets/images folder. Images suffixed with 3, 4, and 5 display correctly, but images 1 and 2 do not. Is it possible that Jekyll/Github only takes images of a certain size threshold?

[image: my assets/images folder]

I believe my _config.yml is configured appropriately. It is at least able to find images 3-5.

```
url : "https://selfawarelemon.github.io/evil-lemonade"
```

For reference, here is how I am referring to all the images within the blog post. Again, this logic works for images 3-5 but not images 1-2.

```
<img src="{{ site.url }}/assets/images/101820_1.png" width="250px">
```

The only difference in each tag is the width I supply to make the images appropriately sized with the width argument. I'm not sure what the issue is here. I've additionally tried waiting a while after a commit to see if it simply takes time to load the images but that didn't work. Is there something super obvious I am missing or simply a property of Jekyll/Github pages I am ignorant to?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the images have been committed to the repository, in the right branch, and pushed to GitHub? Can you open the images directly through the browser via their raw URLs?

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you can point to the exact repository on GitHub...

Comment: Are the images missing when running Jekyll locally, or is it just on GitHub Pages?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments everyone. In order...

1 ) Yes, I have confirmed the changes are being pushed to the correct repository. 
2 ) I can open the images directly through the browser via their raw URLs, but only the ones that load on the website. The ones that do not work bring up 404s.
3) The images are not missing when I run Jekyll locally. The two missing images load correctly locally.

Thankful for any insight you may be able to provide.

Comment: What is the repository on GitHub?

Comment: have you tried changing the extension type case to uppercase of the image file in URL like this `101820_1.PNG` instead of `101820_1.png`?

Comment: Wow, that did it. Good catch, and good to keep in mind for the future. Thank you.

Comment: @selfawarelemon shall I post my answer so that you can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick solution is to keep the case of asset extension (uppercase/lowercase) as it is e.g. https://whoami-shubham.github.io/assets/img/earth.jpg and https://whoami-shubham.github.io/assets/img/earth.JPG would give a different result. 
 In your image path extension of the image is `png` in lowercase however in actual it is `PNG` uppercase. so changing it to uppercase would solve the issue.

```
<img src="{{ site.url }}/assets/images/101820_1.PNG" width="250px">
```

Domain names are case insensitive according to [RFC 4343](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4343).
The rest of the URL may or may not be case sensitive.
for e.g.

- https://stackoverflow.com/Tags
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags

above two URLs give the same result it seems StackOverflow URLs are not case sensitive, However, the following GitHub page URLs are case sensitive.

- https://whoami-shubham.github.io/hello-world
- https://whoami-shubham.github.io/Hello-world

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the image provided, the filenames are capitalized:

```
101820_1.PNG
101820_2.PNG
101820_3.PNG
// ...
```

However, in your image tag, the filename is *not* capitalized:

```html
<img src="{{ site.url }}/assets/images/101820_1.png" width="250px">
```

Capitalizing the filname should fix the issue:

```html
<img src="{{ site.url }}/assets/images/101820_1.PNG" width="250px">
```

Paths in URLs are case-sensitive according to the standard. Depending on the operating system Github Pages is running on, case sensitive image paths may or may not matter. This is probably what is causing the inconsistency in rendering the images.

*This answer was suggested by @shubhamjha in a comment. I created this small answer for future visitors with the same problem*